# Can a Base64 String contain tabs?

Tags: c#, .net, base64

Simple yes or no question, and I'm 90% sure that it is no... but I'm not sure.

Can a Base64 string contain tabs?

Comment: What makes you think it can't?

Comment: Do you mean can you encode tabs using base64 or can should you expect to ever find a tab in a base64 encoded string?

Comment: Ooh: good point lax.  I (and at least three others) assumed the former, but now that I see it spelled out the latter seems more likely.

Comment: Mmm, you win the award for ambiguous question... (at least three meanings).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on what you're asking.  If you are asking whether or not tabs can be base-64 encoded, then the answer is "yes" since they can be treated the same as any other ASCII character.

However, if you are asking whether or not base-64 output can contain tabs, then the answer is no.  The following link is for an article detailing base-64, including which characters are considered valid:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is no - but Base64 cannot contain carriage returns either.

That is why, if you have multiple lines of Base64, you strip out any carriage returns, line feeds, and anything else that is not in the Base64 alphabet

That includes tabs.

Answer (score 3):

From [wikipedia.com:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

> The current version of PEM (specified
> in RFC 1421) uses a 64-character
> alphabet consisting of upper- and
> lower-case Roman alphabet characters
> (A–Z, a–z), the numerals (0–9), and
> the "+" and "/" symbols. The "="
> symbol is also used as a special
> suffix code. The original
> specification, RFC 989, additionally
> used the "*" symbol to delimit encoded
> but unencrypted data within the output
> stream.

As you can see, tab characters are not included. However, you can of course encode a tab character into a base64 string.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Tab is just ASCII character 9, and that has a base64 representation just like any other integer.

Comment: After converting a string to Base64, it can have tabs?

Comment: The encoded string is whatever the encoder created- you can't just insert a tab (or anything else) without breaking the encoding.  A string that has a tab already there can be encoded, and the tab should still be there after decoding.

Answer (score 2):

Base64 specification ([RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.1)) states in [Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.3) that any encountered non-alphabet characters should be rejected **unless explicitly allowed by another specification**:

> Implementations MUST reject the
> encoded data if it contains
> characters outside the base alphabet
> when interpreting base-encoded
> data, unless the specification
> referring to this document explicitly
> states otherwise.  Such specifications
> may instead state, as MIME    does,
> that characters outside the base
> encoding alphabet should    simply be
> ignored when interpreting data ("be
> liberal in what you    accept").
> Note that this means that any
> adjacent carriage return/    line feed
> (CRLF) characters constitute
> "non-alphabet characters" and    are
> ignored.

Specs such as PEM ([RFC 1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421)) and MIME ([RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.8)) specify that Base64 strings can be broken up by whitespaces. Per referenced [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-3.3), a tab (HTAB) is considered a whitespace character.

So, when Base64 is used in context of either MIME or PEM (and probably other similar specifications), **it can contain whitespace, including tabs**, which should be handled (stripped out) while decoding the encoded content.

Comment: Summary of this excellent post: "YES, base64 encoded string IS ALLOWED to contain Tab, Carriage Return etc, if the decoder is programmed to throw away non-conforming characters."

Answer (score 1):

Haha, as you see from the responses, this is actually not such a simple yes no answer.

A resulting Base64 string after conversion cannot contain a tab character, but It seems to me that you are not asking that, seems to me that you are asking can you represent a string (before conversion) containing a tab in Base64, and the answer to that is yes.

I would add though that really what you should do is make sure that you take care to preserve the encoding of your string, i.e. convert it to an array of bytes with your correct encoding (Unicode, UTF-8 whatever) then convert that array of bytes to base64.

EDIT: A simple test.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  string test = "The rain in spain falls \t mainly on the plain";
  sb.AppendLine(test);
  UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
  byte[] b = enc.GetBytes(test);
  string cvtd = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
  sb.AppendLine(cvtd);
  byte[] c = Convert.FromBase64String(cvtd);
  string backAgain = enc.GetString(c);
  sb.AppendLine(backAgain);
  MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is lots of confusion here; and surprisingly most answers are of "No" variety. I don't think that is a good canonical answer.
The reason for confusion is probably the fact that Base64 is not strictly specified; multiple practical implementations and interpretations exist.
You can check out [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more discussion on this.

In general, however, conforming base64 codecs SHOULD understand linefeeds, as they are mandated by some base64 definitions (76 character segments, then linefeed etc).
Because of this, most decoders also allow for indentation whitespace, and quite commonly any whitespace between 4-character "triplets" (so named since they encode 3 bytes).

So there's a good chance that in practice you can use tabs and other white space.

But I would not add tabs myself if generating base64 content sent to a service -- be conservative at what you send, (more) liberal at what you receive.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.FromBase64String()` in the .NET framework does not seem to mind them.  I believe all whitespace in the string is ignored.

```
string xxx = "ABCD\tDEFG";   //simulated Base64 encoded string w/added tab
Console.WriteLine(xxx);
byte[] xx = Convert.FromBase64String(xxx); // convert string back to binary
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(xx));
```

output:

```
ABCD    DEFG
00-10-83-0C-41-46
```

The relevant clause of [RFC-2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) (6:8)

> The encoded output stream must be
> represented in lines of no more
> than 76 characters each.  **All line
> breaks or other characters not
> found in Table 1 must be ignored** by
> decoding software.  In base64    data,
> characters other than those in Table
> 1, **line breaks, and other    white
> space** probably indicate a transmission
> error, about which a    warning
> message or even a message rejection
> might be appropriate    under some
> circumstances.

Comment: I always try an leave a comment when I down vote something unless it's pure and utter crap answer/question.

Answer (score 0):

YES!

Base64 is used to encode ANY 8bit value (Decimal 0 to 255) into a string using a set of safe characters.  TAB is decimal 9.

Base 64 uses one of the following character sets:

```
Data: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
URLs: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_
```

Binary Attachments (eg: email) in text are also encoded using this system.

Comment: Or, by the other interpretation of the question, "NO", since tab is not one of the 64 (26 upper case + 26 lower case + 10 digits + 2 symbols) "digits" used to express a number in base 64.