# How do I send a strings with tab spaces to a website using post requests?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, httprequest

I am trying to read .py files from my machine and post it to my personal website using requests module in python.

Everything is working fine except the indentation.

How do I send tabspaces and multiple new line character with a post request?

Comment: welcome to SO! can you share what you have so far or what you have tried?

Comment: I desperately wanted to automate uploading of .py files from a specific folder on my pc as text on my personal django website without much knowledge of http requests. I watched a few tutorials on python's request module and figured out how to send data. The problem that i was having was the indentation and multiple \n characters was not showing up on the website. Being a beginner in coding it took me few hours to figure out that problem was not because of requests module but of html. Later i fixed that by just using the <pre> tag in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the entire file to base64 (using the base64 module perhaps), send it as the body of the POST request, and then decode it on the other end. This will take care of all ASCII characters (including tabs) as answered here - [Can a Base64 String contain tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285445/can-a-base64-string-contain-tabs)

Comment: Thanks, i used this in another project.